# F# How to preserve lazy /copy a unforced lazy statement

Tags: f#, lazy-evaluation

The output from below is 15,9,9 however I want 15,9,21
I want to preserve a lazy version so I can put in a new function version  in a composed function.

```
open System
let mutable add2  = fun x-> x+2
let mutable mult3 = fun x-> x*3
let mutable co = add2 >> mult3
let mutable com = lazy( add2 >> mult3)
let mutable com2 = com

add2<- fun x-> x
co 3|> printfn "%A"
com.Force() 3|> printfn "%A"
add2<- fun x-> x+4
com2.Force() 3|> printfn "%A"
```

Comment: Perhaps you have a very good reason for trying to take this approach, but it's hard to imagine what that might be. It's very likely you can achieve the final effect that you want without using mutation, and it will be much easier to reason about, but you may need to pass more functions as parameters to other functions. I would need to see more about how you are using these functions in your program to give you better advice about how to structure your code to avoid this problem altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need lazy values here - lazy value is evaluated once when needed, but its value does not change afterwards. In your case, you need `Force` to re-evaluate the value in case some dependencies have changed. You can define something like this:

```
type Delayed<'T> = 
  | Delayed of (unit -> 'T)
  member x.Force() = let (Delayed f) = x in f()

let delay f = Delayed f
```

This represents a delayed value (really, just a function) with `Force` method that will evaluate it each time it is accessed. If you rewrite your code using `delay`, it behaves as you wanted:

```
let mutable add2 = fun x-> x+2
let mutable mult3 = fun x-> x*3
let mutable com = delay(fun () -> add2 >> mult3)
let mutable com2 = com

add2 <- fun x -> x
com.Force() 3 |> printfn "%A"
add2 <- fun x -> x + 4
com2.Force() 3 |> printfn "%A"
```

Unlike lazy, this does not do any caching, so calling `Force` twice will just do the whole thing twice. You could add some caching by tracking a dependency graph of the computation, but it gets more complicated.

Comment: Thank you, was already on my way to use f()->x but this is probably more concise. Though I apologize for my ignorance, but( | Delayed of...  ) is this line for type safety?

Comment: @SvenHeinz - It's just to explicitly define a new type that cannot be confused with ordinary functions. You do not really need that but then the type would be just an alias for any function and type inference would not give you as useful hints as it does when you're more explicit.